# Why doesn't my Mapbox + Leaflet viz look retina-friendly?

Tags: vector, leaflet, mapbox, resolution

This is probably a very simple question but it's not clear to me.

The Mapbox [docs say](https://www.mapbox.com/help/enable-retina-tiles/):

> When you create a project from the editor, Retina (high resolution)
>   tiles are automatically used on devices that supports them. If you are
>   using Mapbox.js, retina tiles are always automatically used when
>   available. No extra code is necessary.

Yet my projection looks fuzzy compared with the map in my Mapbox Projects section.

I use mapbox.js and .css:

```
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v1.0.0/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v1.0.0/mapbox.js'></script>
```

Here are pictures of the respective maps:

The projection (made with Leaflet):

[image: projection]

The project as it appears on Mapbox.com's "Project" page:

[image: mapbox project page]

What mistake am I making?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So that was simple. Searching for mapbox.js, I saw that a newer version is out.

Using the latest css/.js:

```
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.2/mapbox.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.2/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
```

Shows a retina projection.